# what are structural and behavioral design patterns

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns

I am new to design patterns and stuck on very basic step : different types of design patterns.

Creational patters are pretty easy to understand.

I just want to understand the simple definition of **structural and behavioral design patterns**, with explanation in simple terms of java and not in terms of various design patterns.

Note: I read qsns on stackoverflow but I am not clear with the answers. Can anyone explains it in terms of java with simple examples.

Comment: Wouldn't it be helpful to just look at real world examples in Java core APIs? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1673841 Perhaps you've more than often worked with such a class in standard Java and then it helps to realize why it was actually designed that way and so forth.

Answer (score 7):

A **behavioral pattern** is used to abstract some kind of variation in behavior.  One of the most common behavioral patterns is [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).  A good example of the Strategy pattern in Java is the [`Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) method.  The `Comparator` in this method is the Strategy used to determine how the list will be sorted.  There is one `sort` method, but you are free to pass in any number of `Comparator` implementations that effectively control how the sort is performed.  This is the essence of the Strategy pattern.

A **structural pattern** is used to bring together existing objects into some new kind of design.  One of the most common structural patterns is [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).  A good example of the Adapter pattern in Java is the [`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) method.  This method returns an object (the Adapter) that makes the array appear as if it implements the `List` interface, thus allowing you to pass the array to a method that expects an implementation of `List`.

Answer (score 0):

**Structural patterns** focus on relationship in between objects. Group of entities that forms a structure (roughly a data structure). Ex: composite pattern to obtain a collection of object that are manipulated uniformly, see java `TreeNode`. `java.awt.Container` is a typical implementation of composite pattern: a GUI is obtained by aggregating GUI objects (A frame that contains a panel that contains a button and a label) :

```
Container panel = new JPanel();
Container subpanel = new JPanel();
Container button = new JButton("Click me");
// the following is independent of the real nature of objects, except that they are Containers
panel.add(subpanel);
subpanel.add(button);
```

**Behavioral pattern** focus on communication in between objects. Group of entities that communicates (roughly a network of communication). Ex: chain of responsability which lets you obtain a computation from a list of computation entities, see java `Logger`. Java `Iterator` or `Observer` are very common behavioral patterns.

```
Collection<Integer> c = ...
// The following is independent of the real nature of the collection (List, Array, etc.)
Iterator<Integer> i = c.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
   Integer ii = i.next();
   // do something with ii
}
```

Comment: Yunes I have already mentioned that I am new to design patterns and if anyone can explain me in simple terms of java rather then in terms of design patterns, then it would be easier to understand

Comment: The observable Patterns relates 2 objects . The Observer knows the observable and viceversa : "Structural patterns focus on relationship in between objects" . Why is not a Structural Pattern? Am i not creating a larger structure?

Comment: @AlXx Most of patterns relates objects, but the question is more what is the main purpose of these relations? Observer is more focused on the way objects communicates: “**behavioral design patterns** are design patterns that identify common communication patterns among objects".